# Why does Google Drive think the application I created is a virus?

Tags: google-drive

I've created a C#.NET application for research purposes which is certainly not a virus. I packaged it in an MSI installer and put it on Drive for researchers in my lab to download. However, Drive reports the following message when others try to download it:

> Sorry, this file is infected with a virus
>
> Only the owner is allowed to download infected files.

Comment: Do you get any matches if you scan the file at https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload ?

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for the response -- cool site. No matches. They all come back clean.

Comment: I'm actually curious what they are flagging now. What if you upload the application before it is packaged up in an MSI? Perhaps, as suggested below, they are simply paranoid about executables and actively prevent their distribution by shared Drive folders. I wouldn't be too surprised as it would be quite an easy and common vector for drive-by forum link malware blasting.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to mind:

Once or twice a decade I get my code flagged as a virus by one of the major engines.  The culprit appears to be sloppy security work, the compiler was used to write a virus and they identified some library code as a signature.  (When this has happened I have been far from alone.)

Also, Google is quite hostile to executable content.  You don't need a password, just change the extension.  Someone who can't change it back shouldn't be downloading executable content in the first place so this isn't a big problem.